# Dynamically increase the size of a multi select drop down box

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, multi-select

I've implemented this on mouseover and onmouseout like so:

```
<select size="3" onmouseover="this.size=this.options.length;">
```

This is all well and good, except i don't want it only on mouseover, i want it always :) forever.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update it on DomReady.

```
window.onDomReady = function() {
    var a = document.getElementById('yourId');
    a.size = a.length;
}
```

Comment: I suppose this is the only way to do it, i was hoping to be able to somehow declare it within the select tag itself

Comment: You could theoretically create the event for onfocus, and then on load focus the element which will cause the event to trigger.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select size="3" onmouseover="this.size=this.length;">
    <option>hello world 1</option>
    <option>hello world 2</option>
    <option>hello world 3</option>
    <option>hello world 4</option>
    <option>hello world 5</option>
    <option>hello world 6</option>
    <option>hello world 7</option>
    <option>hello world 8</option>
</select>
```

this worked for me :)

Comment: Maybe i didn't explain my question properly but i want it to dynamically increase without the onmouseover action. That is, in your example i want the size to be 8 without the mouseover action.